# One-to many connection can't configure transition by primary key

Tags: python, django

I have a page with car brands and I need to be redirected to the page with all cars of this brand if clicking on a brand. For some reason i can't access to what I need in a tag 'a'.

```
class Marks(models.Model): // MODELS
   mark = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.mark

class Cars(models.Model):
    CarName = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Marks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.CarName



def marks_list(request): // VIEWS
   marks = Marks.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'cars.html', {'marks':marks})

def specific_car(request, pk):
    Car = Cars.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'car_detail.html', {'cars': Car})




    urlpatterns = [
   path('marks/', marks_list), // urls
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('marks/<pk>', specific_car)
]





{% for mark in marks %} // cars.html
<div>
    <a href="{{mark.cars}}">
        {{mark.mark}}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

When clicking on teg 'a' in cars.html i need to get car_detail.html with car names. How should i write a path to 'mark_id'? [App structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQXcr.png)

[Table based on class Cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o47Or.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your template, the variable `mark.cars` is currently undefined. To use it, you have to add `related_name="cars"` to the definition of the ForeignKey field in your class `Cars`:

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    # ...
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Marks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cars")
    # ...
```

Alternatively, you could reference `mark.cars_set` in your template, as `cars_set` would be the default for `related_name` chosen by Django.

The official documentation has a pretty good explanation and examples of what exactly is going on: [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: ValueError at /marks/car_marks.Cars.None
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'car_marks.Cars.None'.

Comment: Yes, now the variable mark.cars is defined, but I admit it doesnt make sense to put it into the link `<a href="{{mark.cars}}">`. Instead, you have to link to an actual url, which you get by `{% url 'mark-detail' mark.id %}`. This requires that in your urls.py, you have a path with the attribute `name="mark-detail"`. I can't tell to which view it should point and correspondingly whether you need to add the attribute name to one of your existing paths, or whether you have to define a new path along with a new view. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-url